# How do I append a value to an array within an array in PHP?

Tags: php

Given this PHP array:

`$options['systems'] = array(1, 2, 3)`

How would I append the value `4` to the `$systems` array within the `$options` array?

Comment: This is basic PHP. Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php and you'll figure something out.

Comment: @AlexBlex They probably want to add it after the array is initialized.

Comment: $options['systems'][] = 4;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to push additional items like so:

```
array_push($options['systems'], 4);
```

Or the shorthand version:

```
$options['systems'][] = 4;
```

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php array_push function. Like this. `array_push($options['systems'],4);`

you can read the detail of array_push from below link.[array_push manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.